# How to create sign parameter value in UPI DeepLink URI

Tags: android, deep-linking, upi

The Deep Link URI string look like

> upi://pay?pa={payee_address}&pn={payee_name}&am={amount}&cu={currency_code}&tn={transaction_note}&sign={sign_key}

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method to generate this `UPI`

```
private fun getUPIString(
    payeeAddress: String,
    payeeName: String,
    payeeAmount: String,
    currencyCode: String,
    transactionNote: String,
    signKey: String,
): String {
      val upi =
            "upi://pay?&pa=$payeeAddress&pn=$payeeName&am=$payeeAmount&cu=$currencyCode&tn=$transactionNote&sign=$signKey"
      return upi.replace(" ", "+")
}
```

Then you do a simple `Intent` to create the chooser

```
val intent = Intent()
intent.action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
intent.data = Uri.parse(upi)
val chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Pay with...")
startActivityForResult(chooser, 1, null)
```

Yo create the sign key you can use :

```
private fun generateSignKey() {
   val secureRandom = SecureRandom()
   val keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator("RSA")
   keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048, secureRandom)
   val keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair()
}
```

Now the `keyPair` contains the private key and the public key, so you need to use the private key for signing the UPI transaction (signKey) payload and the public key for encrypting the payload and also for verifying the signature, make sure you store somewhere secure the private key encrypted.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My question is that where to get/generate the parameter "signKey" which you pass at the last in your function.

Comment: @RahulMishra just edited my answer, let me know if it helps

Comment: Not working! Payment get failed.

Comment: Any update on this?